# Cross-compilation errors Visual studio C++

Tags: c++, linux, debian, cross-compiling, nlohmann-json

I recently converted my Windows C++ application to a Linux c++ application and use a Windows subsystem with Debian to cross-compile to Linux. However, I get the following error by using the json library by [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

```
no match for 'operator-' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type {aka double}' and 'nlohmann::basic_json<>::value_type {aka nlohmann::basic_json<>}')
```

I get this error *everywhere* where I use an operator between a json element and a double for example. As an example:

```
MSE_total += pow(ref.z[j*multiplier] - actual[j]["z"], 2) / pow(ref.z[j*multiplier], 2);
```

This is the line that gives the error above. Should I explicitely state what type of variable is in the json? And how do I do this?

Comment: you should explicitly state what are the types in your example ;) Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `actual[j]["z"].get<double>()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There's [no `operator-` taking a `nlohmann::basic_json`](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json.html). I guess then that

```
ref.z[j*multiplier] - actual[j]["z"]
```

expects `actual[j]["z"]` to be converted to `double` via its [`operator ValueType()`](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a1f1d4bc973c5b866db3d96e14d2c9f3f.html#a1f1d4bc973c5b866db3d96e14d2c9f3f)... and it should (throwing `type_error.302` in case of underlying type mismatch).

Why it doesn't? My bet is on nlohmann's json version number differing from your windows and linux builds.

Workaround: [cast that value to a double](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a6b187a22994c12c8cae0dd5ee99dc85e.html#a6b187a22994c12c8cae0dd5ee99dc85e) (`actual[j]["z"].get<double>()`).